# Moving Canvas Rectangle On touch Issue(center of rect)

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a code where user can move a transparent rectangle on the screen.

The issue i am facing is the rectangle **when i drag is moving from upper left corner as the pivot , whereas i want it to move from center pivot**

**Example**

[image]

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            X = (int) ev.getX();
            Y = (int) ev.getY();
            invalidate();

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            X = (int) ev.getX();
            Y = (int) ev.getY();
            invalidate();
            break;

        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        // draw background
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
        // copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole
        // in it
        c2.drawBitmap(overlayDefault, 0, 0, null); // exclude this line to
                                                    // show all as you draw

        c2.drawRoundRect(new RectF(X, Y, X+350, Y+350), (float)20.0, (float)20.0, pTouch);
        // draw the overlay over the background
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null); 
    }
```

Comment: So subtract half the width/height of the rectangle from X/Y.

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

```
    switch (ev.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

        X = (int) ev.getX();
        Y = (int) ev.getY();
        invalidate();

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

        X = (int) ev.getX();
        Y = (int) ev.getY();
        invalidate();
        break;

    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        break;

    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    // draw background
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
    // copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole
    // in it
    c2.drawBitmap(overlayDefault, 0, 0, null); // exclude this line to
                                                // show all as you draw

    c2.drawRoundRect(new RectF(X-175, Y-175, X+175, Y+175), (float)20.0, (float)20.0, pTouch);
    // draw the overlay over the background
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null); 
}
```

Although what I would do is create an object that has the rect and the center point values so that I could implement a method that would check if i am touching a rectangle then if yes i could move that. What your code does is it will move the rectangle anywhere in the screen that you touched.